# Only show tag with the same id as the post

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms, tags, id

I have been stuck on the following case for a while now. On a page I have a list of `tags` which I try to filter. When the post for example has an `ID` of `10586`, the only tag displayed should be `10586`.

[image]

The name of the `taxonomy` is `post_tag` and the value of the term is the same as the `ID` of the post its on. A post with the `ID` of `10586`, has a term named `10586`.

I tried to accomplish that with this code:

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
{
    global $post;
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $field['taxonomy'] = array();
    wp_reset_query();
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'actor',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tag' => $post_id,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array( 
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post_id'
            )
        )
    ));             
    
    foreach($query->posts as $product_id=>$macthed_product){
            $choices[$macthed_product->ID] = $macthed_product->post_title;
    }
    
    $field['taxonomy'] = array();

    if( is_array($choices) )
    {
        foreach( $choices as $key=>$choice )
        {
            $field['taxonomy'][$key] = $choice;
            if($choice->name == $post->ID){
                $choice = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy' );
            }
        }
    }

    wp_reset_query();
    return $field;
    
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=actor_tags_actor_profile', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

After running the code in functions.php it returns the tags as in the image above.
Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've confused tag/term IDs and tag slugs/names, `10586` is not the ID of the tag, it is the name of the term. `tax_query` also expects term IDs, not the word `post_id`, and `wp_reset_query` should only be used to clean up after a `query_posts` call

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry for the late response. Thank you for the feedback, I shall make adjustments to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to escape the variable $post_id?

Like so:  ''.$post_id.''

So use the single quote twice.

You are querying a slug and your variable is a number.

Comment: I tried to escape `$post_id` in functions.php, but It did not work. Do I need a function to escape it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the tags for a checkbox and applied the following code to only show the checkbox that has a value that is equal to the one of the post it is displayed on.

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
{
    global $post;
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $field['choices'] = array();
    wp_reset_query();
   $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'projectsoverview',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tag' => $post_id
    ));             
    
    foreach($query->posts as $product_id=>$macthed_product){
            $choices[$macthed_product->ID] = $macthed_product->post_title;
    }
    
    $field['choices'] = array();

    if( is_array($choices) )
    {
        foreach( $choices as $key=>$choice )
        {
            $field['choices'][$key] = $choice;
        }
    }
    
     wp_reset_query();
    return $field;
    
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=actor_tags_actor_profile', 'my_acf_load_field');
```